# intellisense for columns in ssms 2012 doesnt work in the body of a stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2012, intellisense, ssms-2012

When I am composing a stored procedure in SSMS 2012, I am not getting intellisense.

I am connected using ssms 2012 to a remote instance of sql server 2012. But i am not getting the wonderful intellisense that I was used to in ssms 2008 R2. It doesn't work for any entity type whether table or column.

The intellisense does work if I am doing standalone queries

At least in the case of tables, after i have finished typing if the table is non-existent it complains. But in the case of columns, it says nothing.

So the issue is two fold

1. There is no intellisense to tell me the possible column names/table names as I am typing
2. After typing is complete, even if the column name is wrong, the ssms IDE doesnt show any squigglies to tell me i am wrong. I only find if i actually execute the query or try to create a stored proc out of it.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, it seems like Microsoft operates with the principle of greatest possible surprise.

If you hit Ctrl+shift+R, things should work.

You can also get to this by doing Edit->Intellisense->Refresh local cache.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No  such luck :(. Please check my latest edits to my question

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried this a number of times this morning and I finally repro'd your issue (no fix even after ctrl+shift+r). Then it just kind of stays in that state. The only thing that seemed to fix it was for me to reinstall SSMS. 
There are some other options in the meantime. First, make sure it is enabled (it's not by default). Tools->Options->editor->TSQL->enable intellisense.
If this were not complicated enough, it can be different in each window, so try CTRLQ+I.
Lastly, make sure you're not in SQLCMD mode.
Sorry mate, stuff like this is frustrating. Hope it helps!